# Python NLTK - Tokenize paragraphs into sentences and words

Tags: python, nltk

I have some text of paragraphs in a .txt file. I am trying to tokenize the paragraphs and append them into a list of sentences and words. I am not sure what I am doing wrong because I have managed to obtain the sentences, but not the words. Been banging my head on the wall for this!

Input:

```
This is sentence one,
Another sentence:
Third line.
```

Desired output:

```
[
 ['This', 'is', 'sentence', 'one', ','],
 ['Another', 'sentence', ':'],
 ['Third', 'line', '.']
]
```

My wrong code and output:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
with open('file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        sentences.append(sent_tokenize(line))

for line in sentences:
    words_token = [word_tokenize(i) for i in line]
    sentences_split_into_words.append(words_token)

----Result----
    [
     [['This', 'is', 'sentence', 'one', ',']],
     [['Another', 'sentence', ':']],
     [['Third', 'line', '.']]
    ]
```

I have also tried but it returns an error 'expected string or byte-like object':

```
for line in sentences:
    sentences_split_into_words.append(word_tokenize(line))
```

Comment: you can read that text file `.txt` using the following code `with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()`, Now u have a list of str, then loop over your data `for sentence in data:` and do `word_tokenize(sentence)` inside the loop. if I did not answer ur question please lemme knw

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! Is it possible to do the tokenization separately for sentences and words? Because I am also doing some processing for the sentences (which works), but just having trouble with the words.

Comment: Yes it is possible, you have already had your sentences in the form of `list` of `str`, so you can use `sent_tokenize` from `nltk` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
with open('file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        sentences.append(sent_tokenize(line))
sentences_split_into_words = []
for line in sentences:
    words_token = [word_tokenize(i) for i in line]
    sentences_split_into_words.extend(words_token)
```

reference: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/extend

Comment: Could you share if the output is what you desired?